# Trying to scrape this page with python but returns gibberish

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried this tutorial from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI&list=WL&index=93

And this is the script which I am trying to scrape a steemit post:
[image]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = 'https://steemit.com/test/@bitcoinfree/test-4'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,'html.parser')
print(page_soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

currently the code is outputting gibberish.

I don't know how to get the pure html source. 
What am I doing wrong ? :(

Comment: check the gzip option of your accept headers

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://steemit.com/test/@bitcoinfree/test-4'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```